# SQL Query without hard coding the datetime value

Tags: .net, sql

I am writing a SQL query using .NET to get the following data:

```
DataReader d = null;
d.executeQuery("select * from table where updated_date >= '11/6/2013 12:00:00'");
```

I do not want to hard code the datetime. How to I intialize a string and insert into the query? I want it to be

```
Datetime value = new Datetime(2013, 11, 6, 12, 0, 0);
select * from table where updated_date >= 'value'"
```

Is this possible?

The limitation is that I have a given set of API's to query the database and a user-defined readerobject. This is my query API:

public void executeQuery(string query)

Comment: The specifics depend on what database you are using, and what mechanism you are using to connect. But nearly all will support this. Look up bind parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var date = new DateTime(2013, 11, 6, 12, 0, 0);
var query = string.Format("select * from table where updated_date >= '{0}'",
                                  date.ToString("MM'/'d'/'yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
```

Notice that I'm specifying that I want / as separator using apostrophes. If you just use / they will be replaced with current culture's date separator. So on my machine

```
date.ToString("MM/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

returns 11-6-2013 12:00:00

Also notice that I'm using single `d` in format string. That returns single digit for months < 10.

Comment: Thanks, but my API accepts only a single argument string query. So i cant use the query you have mentioned.

Comment: What do you mean? I showed you how to create single query. It is named query :) So you call d.executeQuery(query);

Answer (score 3):

I would use the SqlCommand class to do the work:

```
SqlCommand Myquery = new SqlCommand("select * from table where updated_date >= @MyDate");

Myquery.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("MyDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));

Myquery.Parameters["MyDate"].Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that might not work for me. I have a set of API's given to me. They can only by public void execquery(string query). Is there any other way I can pass the query through a string.